# Vias in Kicad are not connecting to the power plane

Tags: power, pcb-layers, kicad

[image]

My other vias are connected with the star pattern to them but my 5V and 10V planes are not actually connected to the vias.  They look like they are but after sending out this board to be made they said my power layer is non functioning.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Couple places to check:

1. Zone fill settings

   - Check that you have default pad connection set to "Thermal Relief"
2. Eeschema nets

   - Check that your 5V is set to the same net.  Do this by placing a power symbol on the network or a global label.

Comment: I have checked both of these and they are correct.

Comment: Can you add the images showing these two items?